# Parameters getting combined in an odd way

Tags: bash

I'm trying to mount an smb share from inside a bash function. The following works from a prompt:

```
mount_smbfs "//domain;user@foo.domain.com/share" ~/mnt/share
```

Inside my function, I have it scripted as:

```
mount_smbfs "//domain\;user@$2" $HOME/mnt/$1
```

I haven't gotten it to work. It just outputs the usage for the mount command. So I added a `set -x` to the start of my function and I can see the command getting executed as:

```
'mount_smbfs //domain\;user@foo.domain.com/share' /Users/user/mnt/share
```

So it looks like the second parameter to mount_smbfs isn't getting passed. Can anyone tell me why not?

**UPDATE**

Here's my function:

```
mnt-prod() {
    set -x
    umount $HOME/mnt/$1
    mkdir -p $HOME/mnt/$1
    mount_smbfs "//domain\;user@$2" $HOME/mnt/$1
    cd $HOME/mnt/$1
}
```

Here's the alias I'm trying to use:

```
alias mnt-share="mnt-prod share foo.domain.com/share;"
```

**SOLUTION**

I ended up with a slightly modified version of the great answer by @ sjnarv:

```
mnt-prod() {
    local dir="$1" host="$2" share="$3"

    umount "$HOME/mnt/$dir" || true
    mkdir -p "$HOME/mnt/$dir" && \
        mount_smbfs "//production;tas@$host/$share" "$HOME/mnt/$dir" && \
        cd "$HOME/mnt/$dir"
}
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the semicolon in your script; that could be the source of your error.

Comment: Are you sure about the placement of single quotes in the command that is being run?

Comment: Show your code: how exactly do you define your function, and how do you call it? It looks like you are doing: `"mount_smbfs //domain;user@$2" $HOME/mnt/$1` with the opening quote in the wrong place.

Comment: I tried with and without escaping the semicolon and it didn't make a difference.  And yes, that's where the single quotes are in the `set -x` output.  That's why I was confused, hence my post here.

Updated to include the function and alias.

Comment: Try `type mnt-share` and `type mnt-prod` to be sure you are running what you think you are.

Comment: Tried that. `mnt-share` is indeed an alias for `mnt-prod`.  And `mnt-prod is a shell function from /Users/user/.zshrc`

Comment: @TimSchmidt: You say `second parameter to mount_smbfs isn't getting passed`, but it looks like in the `set -x` output you do have the `$2` expanded.

Comment: @TimSchmidt Just to be clear, are you running bash or zsh (in the comment you indicate .zshrc while it is taged as bash)

Comment: I can't replicate the single quotes from the `set -x` output in `bash` under Cygwin, CentOS or macOS, or in `zsh` under Cygwin or macOS. Is there some setting affecting argument separators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comment above from @chepner still looks the most relevant. If I leave the \ character present before the ; I see an error like:

```
mount_smbfs: URL parsing failed, please correct the URL and try again: Invalid argument
```

**Longer Answer**

The use of `mount_smbfs` seems to imply the use of MacOS (versus something like `mount.cifs` on various Linux distributions). My comments here reflect trying things out on a Mac.

From the usage message / man page for `mount_smbfs`:

```
mount_smbfs [-N] [-o options] [-d mode] [-f mode] [-h] [-s] [-v]
            //[domain;][user[:password]@]server[/share] path
```

Your function provides values for `domain`, `user`, `server`, and `share`, and constructs `path` using a local convention around the `share` value.

My network environment has its own location-specific details, so rather than hard-wire my localisms into `mnt-prod`, I instead updated the function to use a few more arguments to construct the eventual `mount_smbfs` command in a more generic way. IMO this makes it more flexible, and easier to read and maintain.

Consider the following, which:

- uses local variables to track/document function args 1 through 4
- more consistently quotes values (perhaps you'll eventually have a share name with a space in it)
- uses the `|| true` idiom to let the `umount` command fail benignly in the presence of the `errexit` option (`set -e`)
- uses `&&` to create a `mkdir && mount_smbfs && cd` command list that aborts at the first command failure

The suggested updates:

```
mnt-prod() {
    local domain="$1" user="$2" host="$3" share="$4"

    set -x

    umount "$HOME/mnt/$share" || true

    mkdir -p "$HOME/mnt/$share" && \
    mount_smbfs "//$domain;$user@$host/$share" "$HOME/mnt/$share" && \
    cd "$HOME/mnt/$share"

    set +x
}
```

If my local Mac user name is `jdoe`, my domain name is `MYDOMAIN`, my Samba/SMB/CIFS server is `my.domain.net`, my username `guest`, and share name `public`, usage looks like:

```
$ mnt-prod MYDOMAIN guest my.domain.net public
+ umount /Users/jdoe/mnt/public
umount: /Users/jdoe/mnt/public: not currently mounted
+ true
+ mkdir -p /Users/jdoe/mnt/public
+ mount_smbfs '//MYDOMAIN;guest@my.domain.net/public' /Users/jdoe/mnt/public
+ cd /Users/jdoe/mnt/public
+ set +x
$
```

...and the mount succeeds: local path /Users/jdoe/mnt/public provides access to the remote share `public`.